# Auto load balance Between AWS EC Nginx rtmp server and raspberry pi as client for streaming

Tags: pi-3, streaming-video, nginx

***i am doing live video streaming over the internet with raspberry pi-3  from any where i want to access the live stream (without port forwarding).

so finally i have setup the nginx-rtmp server AWS  on Ubuntu ,  and successfully completed single client streaming pi camera feed with raspberry pi-3 on Internet using this server.
but delay is about 6 to 9 seconds.***

Our Approach

Set up nignx rtmp webserver on AWS EC ubuntu 16.04. sucessfully complete single client streaming Pi Camera Feed with raspberry pi 3 on internet using this server.

Our Problem

We are not able to stream multiple Pi camera with different raspberry pi 3 on nginx rtmp server with delay.we facing larger delay of 8~10 second.

We want

How can we setup nginx rtmp server with multiple client (Raspberry Pi /Android APP user) which can handle all client load balance?

we have setup configuration file on linux based nginx rtmp server as follows:-

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/rtmp_error.log debug;
pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

rtmp {
         server {
                listen 1935;
                chunk_size 4096;
                buflen 1ms;
                application cam_id {
                        live on;
                         allow publish 127.0.0.1;
                        allow publish all;
                        allow play all;
                        record all;
                        record_path /home/video_recordings;
                        record_unique on;
                        hls on;
                        hls_nested on;
                        hls_path /home/hls;
                        hls_fragment 10s;
                        dash on;
                        dash_path /home/dash;
                        dash_nested on;
        }

    }
}
```

We can play video streaming with `rtmp://server-ip/cam_id/live`

Comment: What's the question? How to reduce delay?

Comment: We want to setup nginx rtmp server with multiple clients (Raspberry Pi /Android APP user) which can handle all client load balance.

Comment: This is not RPi-specific. Try asking it on stack overflow.

Comment: @JayEye, if the main problem here is to reduce the delay then it is relevant to this site: the Raspberry Pi has limited capabilities and it is valid to ask for help to use it for computationally-expensive processes. An answer could be an alternative service that can ensure the RPi will run sufficiently fast for this kind of application.

Comment: I don't see anything in the OP that shows the bottleneck is the RPi. At the very least I would expect CPU and memory utilization figures.